# Custom checkboxes in d3 legend not working

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I tried to create checkboxes in d3. On mouse click they should fill with an "x". However `d3.select()` doesn't seem to work inside the click-function, while adding the letter U for the whole legend on click works.

Could somebody please help?

Here is my code:

```
legend.append("g")
        .append("rect")
        .classed("checkbox", true)
        .attr("x", width + 10)
        .attr("height", 18)
        .attr("width", 18)
        .attr("stroke", "#000000")
        .attr("stroke-width", "1")
        .attr("fill", "#ffffff00")
        .attr("checked", "false")
        .attr("id", function (d) {
          return "c" + valueColumns.indexOf(d);
        })

function mouseclick(d) {
      console.log(d);
      console.log(d.target.id)
      d3.selectAll(".checked")
        .style("fill", "#000000") // for testing --> not working
      d3.select(d.target.id)
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", width + 10)
        .attr("dy", "0.65em")
        .attr("dx", "0.65em")
        .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
        .attr("font-size", 24)
        .style("fill", "#000000")
        //.style("color", "#00000000")
        .attr("id", function (d) {
          return valueColumns.indexOf(d);
        })
        .attr("classed", "checked")
        .text("U");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue: I wanted to append a rectangle with text. But rectangles can not contain text so the fix looks like the following:

```
      let checkedLegendElement = d.target.id.slice(1);
      d3.select("#r" + checkedLegendElement) // --> here I am selecting the parent group to append the text
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", width + 10)
        .attr("dy", "0.65em")
        .attr("dx", "0.65em")
        .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
        .attr("font-size", 24)
        .style("fill", "#000000")
        .attr("id", function (d) {
          return valueColumns.indexOf(d);
        })
        .attr("classed", "checked")
        .text("x");
```